# System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper Error when upload Images to Database in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, file-upload

I have a problem here.  When I remove `("Create", "DriverRegs", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })` from my BeginForm, the image path is stored on database normally, but when I put it the above back to the BeginForm, then the image file is stored on my folder but on database appears this error `System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper`.  What is wrong with the codes?
I would appreciate it if someone could help me.
Thanks in advance.

here are my codes:

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Create(DriverReg model, HttpPostedFileBase file)       
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var phisicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(phisicalPath);
                DriverReg newRecord = new DriverReg();
                newRecord.FullName = model.FullName;
                newRecord.Address = model.Address;
                newRecord.Postcode = model.Postcode;
                newRecord.Contact = model.Contact;
                newRecord.Email = model.Email;
                newRecord.County = model.County;
                newRecord.File = phisicalPath;
            }
            db.DriverRegs.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**MODEL**

```
 public class DriverReg
    {
        [Key]
        public int DrvId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        [Display(Name = "Upload Files")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose file to upload")]
        public string File { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }


        internal int UploadImageInDataBase(HttpPostedFileBase file, DriverRegViewModel model)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
    public class DriverDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DriverDbContext()
            : base("VanRemovals")
        {
        }

    public static DriverDbContext Create()
        {
            return new DriverDbContext();
        } 

          public DbSet<DriverReg> DriverRegs { get; set; }
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "DriverRegs", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>DriverReg</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Postcode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Postcode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Postcode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.County, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.County, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.County, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="file" class="file-input" name="file" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you remove the above does it call the same `Action` Method?

Comment: Yes,  it calls create action

Comment: using are saving the wrong object

Comment: It might not be academic writing but I hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the tiny detail that is messing with you, so make changes as indicated with comment

```
  db.DriverRegs.Add(newRecord);//change this part
                db.SaveChanges();
```

**EDIT**

First I don't know how it work's fine when you remove the bit you but then what you want to save is not `DriveReg model` because that is what you are doing. Instead you want to save `DriverReg newRecord`

When the form posts to the controller it posts the file as **`System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper`** so if you save `DriverReg model` that's what you'll have in your database. At that point you haven't done the bit of logic to get the `phisicalPath` as you are showing you want in `DriverReg newRecord`. Since both `newRecord` and `model` are of the same type `DriverReg` it looks as if you are saving the right data but you are not.

Comment: Thanks for your help, question sorted.